# 52 cards, 5 picked, 3 of same suit

Tags: probability

5 cards are drawn from a normal deck of cards (52). What is the probability that 3, and only 3, of the cards are of the same suit?

I'm wondering if my reasoning is sound:

```
C(13,1) * C(4,3) * C(12,2) * C(4,1)^2
-------------------------------------
              C(52,2)
```

Comment: It’s definitely wrong, but it’s not clear what your reasoning actually is. Why, for instance, do you have a factor, $\binom{13}1$, that corresponds to picking a *rank*? (Also, do you mean exactly $3$ in the same suit, or at least $3$?)

Comment: Changing the bottom to be C(52,5) instead, the answer you gave would instead be the probability for three of the same **rank** and two more both of different ranks than one another, not 3 of the same *suit*.

Comment: Are you talking about **only** three cards of the same suit, or could you have four or five cards of the same suit?

Comment: Only 3 of the same suit.

Comment: I think my answer ended up being 3 of a kind and not 3 of the same suit.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is assuming that there must be *exactly* $3$ cards with the same suit.

First, pick a suit, there are $4$ ways of doing this. Next, of the $52/4 = 13$ cards in that suit, pick $3$ of them. There are ${13 \choose 3}$ ways of doing this. Next, of the $52-13 = 39$ cards whose suit is not the one that is picked, pick $2$ of those cards. There are ${39 \choose 2}$ ways of doing this. Now you have a 5-card hand with the specified conditions. Thus, there is a total of $4 \cdot {13 \choose 3} \cdot {39 \choose 2}$ ways of picking a 5-card hand with the specified conditions. The total number of ways of picking a 5-card hand is ${52 \choose 5}$ thus the probability is given by,
$$\frac{4 \cdot {13 \choose 3} \cdot {39 \choose 2}}{{52 \choose 5}}.$$

Comment: I meant 3 and only 3 of the same suit.

Answer (score 1):

3 solutions.

**Solution1:** Exclude 1 suit from 52

**Solution2:** Consider cases for pair or not a pair for the 2 cards left

**Solution3:** Consider cases for cards of same suit or not of the same suit for the 2 cards left

**Solution2:**

4 ways for choose 3 cards from 13. (same suit)

for remaining 2 cards, we have 2 cases to consider:
1. can either have a pair. ( 3 choose 2) from 3 suits left.
2. not have a pair. (3 choose 1) 3 suits left.

$$\frac{{4 \choose 1} \cdot {13 \choose 3} \cdot \left( {13 \choose 2} \cdot {3 \choose 1}^2 + {13 \choose 1 } \cdot {3 \choose 2}\right)  }{{52 \choose 5}}$$

$$=\frac{{4 \choose 1} \cdot {13 \choose 3} \cdot (702+39)}{52 \choose 5}$$

$$=\frac{{4 \choose 1} \cdot {13 \choose 3} \cdot (741)}{52 \choose 5}$$

this would give the same solution as $${39 \choose 2} = 741$$
(exclude 1 suit from 52 cards)

**Solution3:**

$$\frac{{4 \choose 1} \cdot {13 \choose 3} \cdot \left( {13 \choose 2} \cdot {3 \choose 1} + {13 \choose 1 }^2 \cdot {3 \choose 2}\right)  }{{52 \choose 5}}$$

$$=\frac{{4 \choose 1} \cdot {13 \choose 3} \cdot (234+507)}{52 \choose 5}$$

$$=\frac{{4 \choose 1} \cdot {13 \choose 3} \cdot (741)}{52 \choose 5}$$

this would give the same solution as $${39 \choose 2} = 741$$
(exclude 1 suit from 52 cards)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you were looking for would make sure that the remaining two cards would also be of a different suit. This would just be a slight modification of benguin's answer, as he assumes that the remaining two cards could be of the same suit. From the cards remaining, there are  $3 \cdot {13 \choose 2}$ ways to choose two cards from the same suit, because there are 3 suits and 13 cards in each suit. Hence, the overall probability becomes

$$\frac{4 \cdot {13 \choose 3} \cdot \left({39 \choose 2} - 3 \cdot {13 \choose 2}\right)}{{52 \choose 5}}$$

Hope that helps.